# can we pass real time data of ble4.0 to next activity

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to use ble 4.0 data from one activity to other but it's not working for me because it is real time data.

```
 private void displayData(String data) {    
    if (data != null) {

     mDataField.setText(data);
    }
 }
```

I want to use this data into next activity for creating the graphview

```
   @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main3);
    d1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.datavalue);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String  data1 = intent.getStringExtra("data");  
    displayData(data1);
    //Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(this, RBLService.class);
    //bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    line.clear();
}
```

Comment: What is the issue? You can pass data using intent in between activities

Comment: Yes i try to pass data using intent but it's not working for me

Comment: any error you are getting?

Comment: No i did not get any error

Comment: show your code where you are sending the data to other activity

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing data between activities, have just one Activity, displaying several Fragments:

- here is Google doc for that - [Building a Dynamic UI with Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/)
- and a nice 3rd party book - [Creating Dynamic UI with Android Fragments](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/creating-dynamic-ui-android-fragments).

Then you put BLE managing source code into your one and only Activity.

Here is an example of such a class (make your activity `implement BleObject.BleListener` and instantiate a `BleObject` in it with `mBleObject = new BleObject(this, this)`):

```
public class BleObject {
    private Context mContext;
    private BleListener mListener;

    private Handler mRssiReader;
    private Handler mRssiWatchdog;

    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;

    // let your Activity implement this interface (and manage Fragments)
    public interface BleListener {
        public void deviceFound(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi);
        public void updateRssi(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi);
        // add more callbacks here, for example for discovered services
    }

    public BleObject(Context context, BleListener listener) {
        mContext = context;
        mListener = listener;

        mRssiReader = new Handler();
        mRssiWatchdog = new Handler();
    }

    // this method should always be called before using BleObject
    public boolean checkHardware() {
        BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null)
            return false;

        return mContext.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE);
    }    

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled();
    }

    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
        @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                if (device == null)
                    return;

                String address = device.getAddress(); 
                if (!BluetoothAdapter.checkBluetoothAddress(address))
                    return;

                mListener.deviceFound(device, rssi);
            }
    };

    private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                readPeriodicalyRssi();
            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                disconnect();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) {
            if (gatt == null)
                return;

            BluetoothDevice device = gatt.getDevice();
            if (device == null)
                return;

            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                mListener.updateRssi(device, rssi);
            }
        }
    };

    private Runnable mWatchdogRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mGattCallback.onReadRemoteRssi(mBluetoothGatt, -666, BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS);
        }
    };

    private Runnable mRssiRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mBluetoothGatt == null)
                return;

            mBluetoothGatt.readRemoteRssi();
            readPeriodicalyRssi();
        }
    };

    private void readPeriodicalyRssi() {
        mRssiReader.postDelayed(mRssiRunnable, 1000);

        mRssiWatchdog.removeCallbacks(mWatchdogRunnable);
        mRssiWatchdog.postDelayed(mWatchdogRunnable, 10000);
    }    

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void startScanning() {
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mScanCallback);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void stopScanning() {
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mScanCallback);
    }

    public void connect(String address) {
        connect(mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address));
    }

    public void connect(final BluetoothDevice device) {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(mContext, true, mGattCallback);
            }
        });
    }

    public void disconnect() {

        try {
            mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        try {
            mBluetoothGatt.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        mBluetoothGatt = null;
    }
}
```